# Does git revert works with tag?

Tags: git, git-push, rollback, git-revert

I am working with code rollback on my branch, I need to check if git revert works with tags as well ?

Example: `git revert <tagname>`

Also, after git revert, do I need to also run git push on my branch ?

Comment: (This is a question which is very trivial to test out yourself on a token repo, wouldn't have been much longer than posting a question here, if I may)

Comment: I tested It, though the command ran, but I was not able to get how to check if it has actually reverted the code or where the new commit created. newbie to git reset and revert comman, needed some guidance.

Comment: Yes, you need to push after running `git revert` if you want to share those changes with the rest of your team.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a tag name to specify a commit to revert.

For a comprehensive list of ways to specify commit, have a look at this (from git documentation): https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.

And yes, if you want your collaborators to see your changes, you need to push them.

Comment: Yes, IF (and to be honest it's most often the case) the tag is pointing to a commit. If it points to a tree or blob, you can't revert that. Just added for completion, the pragmatic solution above is 99% of the time correct.

Comment: @PiFanatic git push --force origin <branch name> should work or I should not user --force ?

Comment: Avoid `--force` unless you really know why you're using it.

Comment: `git revert` creates a new commit that undoes a previous commit, so a regular push will do, since you're just pushing a new commit at the end of the history.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll try this, also how can I confirm the process?
As in, the revert happened till where the previous tag i.e 1.0.0 (in my case), and HEAD is now at 1.0.0 with new commit.

Comment: [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) undoes specific commits (a single commit or a range/list), it does not restore you to a specific state. You can still `revert` the range of commits up to the current `HEAD`, though, e.g. `git revert -n some_revision..HEAD` and commit the result.